# Instruct browser to only prompt for saving username/password when they have logged in successfully?

Tags: php, coldfusion, authentication, browser

I noticed that some site would trigger the browser to prompt for saving username/password **Only** when they have logged in successfully.  How to achieve that?  response with HTTP 401 / 403 on error along side with the login form with error message?

Right now when I try logging in with invalid username/password, the server will redirect the browser back to the login form with some error message that indicates to the user that the username/password is incorrect, but the browser would ask if the client want to save the username/password which is inappropriate.

Thank you.

Comment: good question, why tag it as coldfusion though?

Comment: @orangepips I guess Henry wants solution in CF, if any.

Comment: **what** is saving the password? Are you talking about the autocomplete for logins that browsers actually save? Or saving information via cookies/sessions?

Comment: If anyone finds any documentation out there on http status codes and http headers that affect the save password feature, please post it.  I have been looking for such a thing for so long.

Answer (score 2):

You could write some javascript to check if the credentials are correct, then if they are submit the form.

Double login but then the form would only be submitted if the credentials are correct.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there's no standard way of doing this, although the topic comes up from time to time.

Comment: Well if some sites do this, there should be *some* way, shouldn't it?

Comment: Some Forum I've been to... phpbb?

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine you could use JavaScript with PHP to check if the user exists, has the right password entered, then JS would also be used to unhide a checkbox in the form or possibly and simply prompt them to save the login credentials.  Let me know if that makes sense.

Now, I see you're asking whether you can disable the inherent browser inquiry in this case.  As far as that goes, you could still follow part of my initial idea and then use browser-specific code to disable the question.  I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0):

I think at least Chrome does a little URL and content checking to figure out if the login was successfull